# Download File In Command

Tags: commands

I'm writing a command that should end up downloading a file for the user who clicks the button associated with the command. `SheerResponse.Download` requires a file and there doesn't seem to be an override for anything else. Is there an equivalent function that takes a stream? I do not want to save a file on the server when creating this file if possible.

Comment: Is using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions an option? There are already built-in ways to do this.

Comment: @MichaelWest it is but then I think I would need to rework what I have done already so if there's a way to do it in a command that would be ideal.

Comment: @Teeknow why don't you create the file and then downloads it. You can delete the file programmatically by using an agent to delete them. Else, you'll require to implement an extension of the download to allow stream.

Comment: @HishaamNamooya if there isn't an out of the box way to do this that's the route I'm going to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current OOTB feature to download file via stream in Sitecore as far as I know. As Michael suggested in the comment above, you can use **Sitecore Powershell**.

Another option is to save the file on the server itself, like for example in the `Data` folder, and then download it using the `SheerResponse.Download`. At the end of the day, you may have an agent which removes the files.

If you still want to use the stream to download, you will require to implement an extension of the download feature to pass the stream as parameter. There are lots of links on the net which explains how to do it. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558317/how-to-download-memorystream-to-a-file

Based on my previous experience, I had a similar task where I need to generate and download a `csv` file on command click (SPE wasn't available yet). The issue I've gone through was

1. Files got messed up in terms of content.
2. Not the whole file was downloaded.

Comment: That's kind of a bummer but worth knowing. I think I'll look into creating an extension to deal with this on my own time but for now I'm going to just save the file and use `SheerResponse.Download`. Thanks!