# Links to CSV download in the browser

Tags: content-editor

> I want to export sitecore redirect links to a csv file. Created in the
>   ribbon a button, and the code referend page in the project.(see below)

```
public class ExportRedirectsListCmd : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        var RedirectFolder = new SitecoreContext(GetContentDatabase()).GetItem<BaseCommon>(context.Items[0].ID.ToGuid(), context.Items[0].Language);
        var lstLinkToRedirect = RedirectFolder.Children.OfType<LinkToLinkRedirect>();
        var filename = "RedirectsOutput_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"{"Redirecttype"},{"Sourcelink Url"}, {"Targetlink Url"}");
        // collect all information 
        var allLines = (from item in lstLinkToRedirect
                        select new object[]
                        {
                                           item.RedirectType,
                                           item.SourceLink.Url,
                                           item.TargetLink.Url
                        }).ToList();

        // insert the content
        allLines.ForEach(line =>
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
        });

        //saves file to temp folder. This works, but not for a user
        var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
           var tempFilename = Path.GetTempFileName();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tempPath + tempFilename , sb.ToString());

        // Alertbox just for test
        // SheerResponse.Alert(sb.ToString());
        // return;
    }
}
```

Code collects all information in the stringbuilder. By test the alertbox displays the expected information.

Now to download the stringbuilder information to the browser. HttpContext does not work in sitecore. Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Comment: You can use the `SheerResponse.Download`. More info can be found at the question here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/download-file-in-command/7101#7101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Besides the usefull help"(thanks Hishaam), it still didn't work inside the content editor.
Answer: It's a ajax async call, so start a new procedure (DownloadFile).

Tip, use => sitecore.io <= TempFolder.Folder.

In code it looks like

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Sitecore.IO;

  public class ExportRedirectsListCmd : Command
  {
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
     var filename = "RedirectsOutput_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm") + ".csv";
            // Combined name of Sitecore temp path and filename 
     var file = FileUtil.MapPath(Path.Combine(TempFolder.Folder, filename));

        //Get the link information and write to disk 
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"{"Redirecttype"},{"Sourcelink Url"}, {"Targetlink Url"}");
        File.WriteAllText(file, sb.ToString());

        // create a new (sitecore) async run to deploy a download insite the content editor 
        var args = new ClientPipelineArgs();
        args.CustomData.Add("File", file ?? "");
        args.CustomData.Add("Path", TempFolder.Folder ?? "");
        args.CustomData.Add("FileName", filename ?? "");
        Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DownloadFile", args);
        Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DeleteOldFiles", args);
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// This procedure run after the execute. Now it's possible to fire some code to the UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// inject in args the string filepath with file name
    /// args.CustomData["file"] = 
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private void DownloadFile(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (!Context.IsAdministrator)
        {
            SheerResponse.Alert("Only administrators can download files.");
        }
        else
        {
            var file = args.CustomData["File"] as string;
            SheerResponse.Download(file);
        }
    }
}
```

With all credits to Paul for this solution. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the `StringBuilder` with the appropriate data, you can generate the `.csv` file and store it within the website folder.

Once the file is generated, you can make use of the following code to download the file.

Either

```
SheerResponse.Download(file.FullName);
```

Or

```
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Download(file.FullName);
```

Make sure that you provide the proper path of the file within the `Download()` method.

**UPDATE**

Based on the chat discussion, you can provide the user a window where the list of files are listed. Then, they can select the desired file and click on the download button.

Example, the Sitecore Installation Wizard (selection of package) is pretty much the same thing you want to achieve.

[image]

You can check the code from the below namespace to see how Sitecore does it.

```
Namespace: Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.BrowseDialog
Assembly: Sitecore.Client.dll
```

Comment: Thank you Hishaam, but unfortunate it's not working.
I edited the code. 
In there file.writealltext saves a temp file. That's no problem. 
But whatever I do  Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Download(tempPath + tempFilename) won't work. It gives not even an error.

Comment: @Dinand can you update the question with your updated code for creating the file?

Comment: I did before writing the comment... Please reply if you don't see it in the question. It's the last part

Comment: @Dinand I don't understand the following comment `This works, but not for a user` and can you share what is the path and file name you get from the `GetTempPath` and `GetTempFileName`

Comment: The file I saved is in a temp map and intended to be temporary. It's also not user friendly. A custom map would not be a good plan, you don't known there environment. I want to offer a download in the browser. So saving on disk works..and is readable for the download function.

Comment: Yes you can save it on the disk within the website folder as specified above. The you can generate the download link. Additionally, you may have a task which removes the files at a certain time.